# How can I send pictures from my Sony Alpha 7R to my mobile without the "PlayMemories Online" app?

Tags: sony, file-transfer, sony-alpha

I don‘t want any of my photos in the cloud and the ‚playMemories Online‘ app is complete non-functional crap (got 1 star in my appstore).

Is there another way to transfer images wirelessly to the mobile phone?

Comment: Does it have to be wirelessly?  Because there are several memory card readers that can plug into both iPhone and Android phones

Comment: I can't believe there is no good answer to this. I guess recompiling for 64-bits was too much for the hard-working engineers at Sony?

Answer (score 1):

According to Sony, their [Imaging Edge Mobile app replaces Sony Play Memories](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/articles/00227867):

> The Imaging Edge™ Mobile app is the successor to the PlayMemories Mobile™ app. All the features from the previous app can be used in Imaging Edge Mobile.

However, this seems to also be a cloud-based solution, at least in part. Images transferred through Imaging Edge can be up to 2 MiB, which I infer to mean that images uploaded to the cloud us are limited to 2 MiB.